# How to convert current ubuntu system to a bootable iso?

Tags: 14.04, boot, iso

I have a ubuntu 14.04 PC with various packages installed, I need to convert my system to a bootable iso so that I can boot it from some other device and install similar filesystem and kernel to other PC.

Comment: In other words you want to create a clone ? If so try [clonezilla](http://clonezilla.org/).

Comment: Take a look at [Systemback](https://launchpad.net/systemback).

Answer (score 0):

**Ubuntu is portable also as an installed system**, unless you have installed proprietary drivers (for example for graphics and wifi). This makes it possible to clone with [Clonezilla](http://www.clonezilla.org/) (or make a compressed image, that can be installed into other computers) as suggested by George.

But if you want to use the systems in the same LAN, and if you want to have separate user IDs, you can make an OEM install with your extra program packages installed. After cloning the OEM will let you make individual systems.

See this link: [OEM Installation](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Ubuntu_OEM_Installer_Overview)

-o-

It is possible but much more complicated to create a custom iso file.